# Bootstrap image isn't visible

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make logo but image isn't showing up. Can someone tell me why it's not working? Why min and max width/height arent working here?

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="head">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-2 logo"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container-fluid {
  padding: 15px !important;
}
.logo {
  background-image: url("../images/logo.png");
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 300px;
  min-width: 50px !important;
  min-height: 30px !important;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just put the actual image in there instead of setting it as a background?

Comment: Is the URL correct? (if not you'd be getting a 404 on console). You may add `background-size: cover` so the image takes as much space to fit inside the container. Any reasons to do this approach instead of actually using the `img` tag?

Comment: Looks your background-img url is wrong, make sure you have the correct path. You can check there your code: http://www.bootply.com/QR8kOyHSfM

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention the `background-size` property for the image to fill in the area defined.

Try this,

```
.logo {
  background: url("../images/logo.png") no-repeat;
  background-size : contain;
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 300px;
  min-width: 50px !important;
  min-height: 30px !important;
}
```